# subject-verb agreement: the dependency of A and B on C ... (to be) taken into account

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Considering the sentence

> The **dependency of** the length **and** electrical conductivity **on** temperature ... taken into account,

since 'dependency' as the head of the noun phrase 'The dependency of the length and electrical conductivity on temperature' is singular (or uncountable; I'm not sure.) we should use the verb 'is', rather than 'are', here. Am I correct?

Comment: Thank you @BillJ. Isn't there any difference between "A and B" and "dependency of A and B on C" in this regard?

Comment: Looking at it again, "length" and "electrical conductivity" form a coordination of NPs as complement of the preposition "of". That being the case, the subject as a whole is just one NP whose head is the singular noun "dependency", and hence a singular verb is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The subject is "dependency", and so a singular verb, such as "is" and not "are", is required.

Sentences like this commonly trip up even fluent English speakers. We learn to see two words connected by "and" and think "plural" and so use a plural verb, but that's just wrong.

A simple trick that I was taught in school is to drop prepositional phrases and other "side" words to simplify the sentence, and then the correct choice of verb is often obvious. Like in this case, think of the "core" sentence as "The dependency (is/are) taken into account". Now it should be much more clear that the correct verb is "is".